# How to create query rule to boost people search results where lastname contains query?

Tags: 2013, search, ranking, query-rule

I want to define a query rule (?) to boost people results that contain the last name in the query (using SharePoint 2013), basically I want to rank the results where the query is contained in the lastname/firstname field higher than where the query is only contained in another field (e.g. "Ask me about").

This of course should be done in the ranking model, but somehow this doesn't always work. I would like to create a simple rule that basically says *"if {query} is contained in [LastName] or [FirstName], then boost result entry to the top"*.

Possible with query rules? Possible with something else? `XRANK`?

Comment: 2010 or 2013 (since search terminology is quite different between them)?

Comment: Perfectly good question. **2013**

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SharePoint 2013 it should be something like:

```
({SearchBoxQuery} XRANK(cb=2000) Lastname:{SearchBoxQuery}) XRANK(cb=1000)  Firstname:{SearchBoxQuery}
```

Boosting match on last name by 2000, on first name by 1000 and on both by 3000

Comment: Ah so not really a query rule? I could just add this to the search result WebPart. (*2013 is correct*)